# How to safely remove items from arrays inside setTimeout callbacks

Tags: javascript, timer, race-condition

I have a function that receives an object and an optional expiry time, assigns a unique id to that object and inserts it to an array. And if an expiry time was provided, sets a timeout callback which finds the object in the array by its unique id and removes it.

```
  var lastId = 0;
  var messages = [];

  function add(messageObj, expiryTime) {
    var newId = ++lastId;
    messageObj['_id'] = newId;
    messages.push(messageObj);

    if (expiryTime) {

      // find message object to remove
      setTimeout(function() {
        var index = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
          if (messages[i]['_id'] == newId) {
            index = i;
            break;
          }
        }

        // at this point, if another callback removes an item from the array, then we have a race condition
        messages.splice(index, 1);
      }, expiryTime);
    }
  }
```

Now, my questions is: are there any race conditions here (and if so, how to handle it), or is it safe to do this kind of thing in javascript timers?

Comment: You get a single thread of execution. There are no data races.

Comment: this is interesting. do you mind me asking what it is that you are trying to build with this?

Comment: Yep, there is not race condition, like say @squint Javascript is single thread.

Comment: @DaMaxContent Nothing fancy, just a simple angularjs service that shows notifications and optionally hides them after some time.

Comment: aah. Angular. something I need to learn.

Comment: @squint thank you. So all JS implementations are single threaded, correct?